# QPaint translation scale with mouseevent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I need to draw a shape with scaling and `Qwheel event`. I have tried `painter.scale` and `painter.translate`, but it does not at all effect the scaling of shape.

The idea is to draw different shapes, for instance this one on ***the figure below***, a rectangular shape with start value **( 200, 300)** looks perfect and even centered at `canvas widget`. but when with greater value **( 500, 700 )** as shown on ***second below figure*** enlarges and becomes unwanted. I want to draw it with scale and with ability to wheel ***(zooming in and out)*** it with `mouse event`.

**Visualization.**

[image]

[image]

**The code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 700, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self._width = 200
        self._height = 300


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense5Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint((self.width() - self._width)/ 2, (self.height() -self._height)/ 2), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        painter.drawRect(r)
        painter.scale(0.4,0.4)
        painter.translate(50, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I appreciate muchhh any help. Thanks

Comment: mouse event or wheel event?

Comment: Which one is more flexible? use wheel event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale is given with respect to the top-left so if we want it to scale with respect to the center it must first be moved there, and after scaling it is placed in the initial position. For the case of the scale factor, use the `wheelEvent` method using the `angleDelta()`, multiplying by an appropriate factor.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 700, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(200, 300))
        self._factor = 1.0

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.r.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense5Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        painter.translate(self.rect().center())
        painter.scale(self._factor, self._factor)
        painter.translate(-self.rect().center())

        painter.drawRect(self.r)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self._factor *= 1.01**(event.angleDelta().y()/15.0)
        self.update()
        super(Paint, self).wheelEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I want. But 2 questions arise, is there a better way to get smoother pixelchange in case wheel forward and backward? do we obtain the same behavior by using `MouseEvent`?

Comment: @ZarKha Why do you want to use mouse event? How to indicate with the mouse that there is zoom or zoom out?

Comment: I am just curious. for instance left click is zoom out and right click zoom in.